# Silverlight Webpart get list items

Tags: c#, silverlight, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

i'm trying to create a silverlight wepart to get the listItems from a SharePointList.

```
void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ListName);
    clientContext = ClientContext.Current;
    oWebsite = clientContext.Web;
    List myList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(ListName);

    CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
    ListItemCollection listItems = myList.GetItems(query);

    clientContext.Load(listItems);
    clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);

 }

private void onQuerySucceeded(object sender, ClientRequestSucceededEventArgs args)
{
    UpdateUIMethod updateUI = DisplayInfo;
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(updateUI);
}

private void DisplayInfo()
{
    foreach (ListItem listItem in listItems)
    {
        label1.Content += listItem.FieldValues["Typ"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Its loading the list but somehow its not loading the listItems and values... 
does anyone know how to get the values of the listItems for a specific field.

Thanks in advance
Ebru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for you fast response!

I did it in this way :

```
 foreach (ListItem listItem in listItems)
   {
     textBox1.Text += listItem.FieldValues["File_x0020_Type"].ToString();
   }
```

In Silverlight you can only access fieldValues of listItems with internal fieldNames! [look here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michael_yeager/archive/2008/11/03/reference-list-for-internal-field-names.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the fields in this way:

```
foreach (ListItem listItem in listItems)
    {
        label1.Content += listItem.item["Title"] + " : " + listItem.item["Typ"];
    }
```